# Martial arts Kung fu attire

Tags: kung-fu

What are those button up martial arts shirts called seen in anime or kung-fu movies.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The figure on the left is shown wearing a traditional kung-fu style uniform shirt with frog buttons. You may also have seen them referred to as "Mandarin" style shirts. In Mandarin, they're referred to as "Yi-Fu", which translates to "clothing".

These actually were the style of clothes worn traditionally by everyone in China up until the 1940's or so. It wasn't particular to kung-fu. But kung-fu styles have kind of adopted it over time as the standard uniform. It's just traditional. Nowadays people in China wear Western style clothing more often than traditional Chinese garments, especially in big cities.

Hope that helps.